# Different Target for Deref and DerefMut

Tags: rust, ffi, dereference, rust-pin

I am trying to create a wrapper type around a `cxx::UniquePtr<A>`.

I want to implement `struct B(UniquePtr<A>)` with

`Deref<Target=UniquePtr<A>> for B`

but also

`DerefMut<Target=Pin<&mut A>> for B {}`

Is this a terrible idea or even possible? The whole point of `B` is to hide the type complexity of `UniquePtr<A>`. Right now I am forcing my users to call `.pin_mut()` every time they want to do something and it is quite ugly and breaks their code auto completion. Does anyone have any suggestions or resources I should look at to clean up the interface?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. `DerefMut` does not define a type `Target`, it _inherits_ it from the required `Deref` implementation, so as I understand it, `<B as Deref>::Target` and `<B as DerefMut>::Target` must be the same type.

Comment: It's both impossible and a bad idea. `&*x` and `&mut *x` should never result in a reference to different types. That would be horribly confusing.

Comment: And `.deref_mut()` must yield a `&mut Target`. So you can't wrap the return type in a `Pin` anyway (unless you did `&mut Pin<&mut A>` which would not be desirable either).